# ucesols, string out of range

Tags: python, list, load

i want to read 3 columns out of one TXT file....

I started with np.loadtxt:

```
data_locs,data_date, data_metar=np.loadtxt(path, usecols=(0,1,21), delimeter=',', skiprows=1)
```

The file looks like that:
[image]

I want to extrakt the three different columns to get:
station, valid, metar

can someone help me?

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you one column..you get others like this without loading the whole file:

```
result = []
with open("yout_txt.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        result.append(line.split(',')[1])
```

Comment: The problem is that if a read everything, the process is interupt. The txt is to big.

Comment: Updated the answer as per your ask and split by comma as you .txt file has commas

Comment: If this solves your problem, do upvote and accept for future users